# Generate Random Alphanumeric String in D

Tags: twitter, random, d

I'm looking for a platform independent way to generate a random alphanumeric string for a Twitter nonce. Currently I'm using this but it depends on `/dev/random` which is obviously UNIX-specific:

```
private auto _getNonce() {
    ubyte[32] buffer;
    File devRandom  = File("/dev/random", "rb");
    auto randomData = devRandom.rawRead(buffer);
    auto randomBase = Base64.encode(randomData);

    auto nonWords   = regex(r"[\W_]", "g");
    return replaceAll(randomBase, nonWords, "");
}
```

This follows [the recommendation in the Twitter development documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request) to get 32 bytes of random data, base-64 encode them and strip all non-alphanumeric characters.

The nonce doesn't have to be cryptographically secure, it's just used to prevent duplicate submissions. Any suggestions for a better way to do this which works on Windows as well as UNIX?

Comment: Why simply not using std.random (http://dlang.org/phobos/std_random.html) module??

Comment: @DejanLekic Looking for a more complete solution, that just generates numbers up to ulong (which I can only count on being 32-bit). I need an alphanumeric string and all the ways I can think of are pretty hacky.

Comment: You can do with std.random exactly what you do in your example. Base64 encoding is also in Phobos...

Comment: @DejanLekic I know Base64 encoding is in Phobos, I'm using it in my example. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: After all these years I should point out that `randomCover` does not repeat. Meaning this solution will only provide a character once in lower case and once in upper case. I looked at using `cycle()` to remedy this but `randomCover` doesn't support infinite ranges.

If all you need is 32 alphnumeric characters:

```
import std.algorithm : fill;
import std.ascii : letters, digits;
import std.conv : to;
import std.random : randomCover, rndGen;
import std.range : chain;
import std.stdio : writeln;

void main() {
    // dchar[] are random access, strings (char[]) are not
    auto asciiLetters = to!(dchar[])(letters);
    auto asciiDigits = to!(dchar[])(digits);

    dchar[32] key;
    fill(key[], randomCover(chain(asciiLetters, asciiDigits), rndGen));
    writeln(key);
}
```

The [range documentation](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#.isRandomAccessRange) specifically states

> static assert(!isNarrowString!R); // narrow strings cannot be indexed as ranges

narrow strings being char[] and wchar[]. While they are arrays, one cannot find "character" 2,531 in O(1) preventing these types from being considered random access, which is required by randomCover.

Comment: What do you mean `char[]` isn't random access? That seems wrong to me. `string` isn't mutable, but `char[]` is, if that's what you meant?

Comment: Ah, you've been talking about unicode characters. Yeah, point taken.

Answer (score 3):

std.random should work just fine. It has a variety of random number generators if you care what type you use, but `std.random.rndGen` uses `Mt19937`, which is an implementation of [Mersenne Twister MT19937](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MT19937). And std.random's number generators are ranges, which makes them interact really well with the rest of Phobos.

One possible implementation

```
string genNonce()
{
    import std.algorithm, std.ascii, std.base64, std.conv, std.random, std.range;

    auto rndNums = rndGen().map!(a => cast(ubyte)a)().take(32);

    auto result = appender!string();
    Base64.encode(rndNums, result);

    return result.data.filter!isAlphaNum().to!string();
}
```

`rndGen()` generates an infinite range of random numbers. `map!(a => cast(ubyte)a)()` then lazily converts them to `ubyte`. And `take(32)` lazily takes the first 32 of them so that the resultant range has a length of 32 instead of infinity. `Base64.encode` is then used to encode that in an output range, and that is filtered so that it only contains alphanumeric characters and converted to `string`.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I had in mind when I asked Suhosin why he does not use std.random ... :) Looks like he wanted some piece of source... ;) Well done as usual, Jonathan!

Comment: @DejanLekic Source is always ideal, but a pointer to correct functions would have sufficed. I don't find the Dlang documentation the easiest thing to follow. :P

Comment: Doesn't this `a => cast(ubyte)a` drop a huge part of the generated random bits? I guess `a => *cast(ubyte[a.sizeof]*)&a` would be better but it's ugly. And now you have a range of ubyte[4] and phobos does not seem to have a function to flatten a range of ranges.

Comment: @jpf Except why would you care about what size the original number was? The 8 bits you're using are still randomly generated. It's normal to generate numbers far larger than you use, and the typical thing to do is to use `%` to reduce the value to the range that you want. So, you could use `cast(ubyte)(a % ubyte.max)` instead, but I don't think that that's really any different from just casting if what you care about is all numbers that fit in a `ubyte`. But you can do something like you're suggesting if you really want to. The key part of the answer here really is to use std.random.

Comment: Well, generating more random data than necessary could impact performance. But as long as profiling doesn't show this as a bottleneck it probably doesn't matter.